# Can I apply the same animation to multiple text fields?

Tags: ios, facebook-pop

I'm creating a method that shakes my UITextField and use POP to do the heavy lifting.

```
- (void)textFieldErrorAnimation {

    POPSpringAnimation *shake = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerPositionX];

    shake.springBounciness = 10;
    shake.velocity = @(2000);


    [self.value.layer pop_addAnimation:shake forKey:@"shakeValue"];
    [self.year.layer pop_addAnimation:shake forKey:@"shakeYear"];
}
```

It seems to be working when I apply the animation to the object "value" but not when it's applied to "value" and "year" at the same time.

I know I can create a shake2, shake3 etc so basically one for each textField but it seems strange that i'd need to do that.

Any ideas how I can reuse this animation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can. What I really do about, this kind of reusing animations is creating a method that returns the animation and setting the name and key values correctly.

```
- (POPSpringAnimation *)popShakeAnimation {


POPSpringAnimation *shakeAnimation = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerPositionX];
shakeAnimation.velocity = @2000;
shakeAnimation.springBounciness = 20;
shakeAnimation.name = @"shakeAnimation";

return shakeAnimation;
```

}

and then whenever I need to shake any views I simply add them to the views' layer.

```
    [self.textfield001.layer pop_addAnimation:[self popShakeAnimation]
                                            forKey:@"shakeAnimation"];
    [self.textfield002.layer pop_addAnimation:[self popShakeAnimation]
                                            forKey:@"shakeAnimation"];
    [self.textfield003.layer pop_addAnimation:[self popShakeAnimation]
                                              forKey:@"shakeAnimation"];
```

Just remember to set key values to the name you've created with the animation in the first place.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. So the proper practice would be to set the 'name' property to the animation object name and then use this as the key?

Comment: That's the point dude. Just don't forget to name it properly and setting it as the key too.